# Win_Template - how can I replace only the variables alone and not the entire property file using jinja?

Tags: ansible

My requirement is to replace variables (specific to respective environment property file) on the Windows server as part of the deployment. Tools used are Jenkins, Bitbucket and Ansible

I am new to using Ansible and I am trying to use Jinja templating for this requirement and below is my code.

```yaml
- name: Transform environment specific values using jinja template
  win_template:
    src: CredentialsFile.j2
    dest: D:\apps\wwwroot\application\Web.config
```

The above code is entirely replacing the `web.config` file with the values in `.j2` file. But, what I need is to replace only the variables, not the entire config file. How can I change the above task to fulfill my requirement ?

Comment: Use `lineinfile` and/or `blockinfile`unfortunately those modules do not run on Windows. So you will have to slurp/fetch the file contents on the controller, do the operation there and copy the file back to the Windows host.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer you will have to be more specific: show your template, show an example of the current file on the server, explain the parts your want to replace and the ones you don't want to.